# Cases created via REST API bypass escalation rules

Tags: rest-api, case, escalation

I noticed that Cases created via REST API bypass escalation rules. It's as if they don't exist when checking in the escalation monitor.

Is there a best-practice way to get them to follow normal escalation rules, even if it's something after the fact in Process Builder?

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed that Cases created via REST API bypass escalation rules.

No, it doesn't. I just tested this.

> It's as if they don't exist when checking in the escalation monitor.

Maybe your search criteria is incorrect?

> Is there a best-practice way to get them to follow normal escalation rules, even if it's something after the fact in Process Builder?

You don't need to do anything special, they will work normally in the REST API.

---

You'll want to debug using the Developer Console to see what's going on. Open the Developer Console in one window, then use Postman or Workbench to create a record, and then check the logs to see the escalation rules at work. It'll tell you which criteria are met, if any, and which rule entry the case was assigned to.